# chkconfig modification dosen't takes effect

Tags: networking, services, wpa-supplicant, chkconfig

I use *CentOS release 6.5 (Final)* and I would like that *wpa_supplicant* service start after *network* service.
When I go to */etc/rc5.d* and I type *ls* command, I can see :

```
K84wpa_supplicant -> ../init.d/wpa_sup
S10network -> ../init.d/network
S23NetworkManager -> ../init.d/Network
```

The content of */etc/init.d/network* is :

```
# chkconfig: 2345 10 90
```

The content of */etc/init.d/wpa_supplicant* is :

```
# chkconfig: - 23 88
```

I changed the *90* to *88* and the *88* to *90* but when I restart my *CentOS*, the *network* service always start after *wpa_supplicant*.
How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

In this init script the '10' refers to the start position, while the '90' refers to the kill position.

```
# chkconfig: 2345 10 90
```

By changing 90 to 88, and 88 to 90, you are only changing the positions of which processes *stop* first. In this case, your wpa_supplicant init script starts at position 23, while network starts at position 10, so these are the numbers that will need to be changed in order to manipulate the startup order of each script.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I understand that I need to compare only the _S_ to view the order of services start. So in the current configuration, _network_ starts at position _10_ so before _wpa_supplicant_. Why I can't see _wpa_spplicant_ service in _/etc/rc5.d_ for exemple ? I only see the _K84wpa_supplicant -> ../init.d/wpa_sup_ and **not** _S23wpa_supplicant -> ../init.d/wpa_sup_

Comment: Essentially there are two ways to modify start/stop positions of init scripts. One is to adjust the numbers in the init script like we have discussed:

Comment: Woops, pressed enter too soon. Let's try this again.

Comment: Essentially there are two ways to modify start/stop positions of init scripts. One is to adjust the numbers within the actual init script like we have discussed:

    # chkconfig: - 23 88

The other is to mv/rename the scripts within each /etc/rc{0,6}.d directory with a K or S and number to reflect the location. But these are really just symlinks to the actual script in /etc/init.d.

The wpa_supplicant init script, instead of specifying that it starts for runlevels 2, 3, 4, 5 the way your network script does, has a dash (-). I believe this is linked to the reason it's not in /etc/rc5.d.